# Visual Studio: Blank window after selecting create new project from existing code

Tags: visual-studio

I have cloned a folder via git and I would like to create a new project within the folder.
In the past, I was able to do this by pressing file > create new project from existing code but today when I try the same thing I just get a blank white window with the title 'create new project from existing code'.

Is this an error with visual studio, or did I miss a step?

Comment: It is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/769977/hangs-on-create-new-project-from-existing-code-fil.html) they don't seem interested in fixing.  Add your vote.

Comment: @HansPassant Dang. is there a different way to add C++ files to an existing folder?

Comment: I can't make much sense out of "existing folder".  Consider adding them to a *project*, Project > Add Existing Item.  Select as many as you want by shift-clicking files.

Comment: @HansPassant What I meant was create a project inside of an existing folder (without clicking create new project from existing code) that does not have any code files